# How to list a hybrid app in mobile chrome share option?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-chrome

I'm building a hybrid app using Apache cordova.I need my *app to list in the google chrome(mobile) share option* to share the current url to my app.how can i make this possible? helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make this more clear if you want to add share plugin into app or anything else, also share the code you have tried to make it possible.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Actualy i just need to grab the url from chrome to my app.i do not have much code to show but i come up with this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent .but im not sure this is the right solution.

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible using native app first ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda yes ofcourse, when we click the share option in chrome it lists almost all the native apps.

Comment: @vivek Did you checked out this plugin - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try This, may be help you

Put the below line into

**platforms/android/android-manifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: ok,since its a hybrid app i dont think i can directly edit the android manifest file.Is there any plugins are available to customize the config.xml?.

Comment: No, you can directly edit that file and set the value you want.

Comment: I am working into Phonegap from last 1 year, and I don't think there is any need of plugin to edit any android file directly, I have already asked you if this is possible via native app then you can do the same with adding some native code. So you can do it.

Comment: Ok fine I'll check that.